# how to rsync the directory structure and only one file within each folder between two servers?

Tags: command

I have gigantic data consisted of branching tree of folders, sub folders, sub-sub folders and sub-sub-sub folders. Inside the terminal sub folder, I have large number of images (~ 2000 image each file is ~ 5-- kib ) which makes opening the folders very hard and slow. The images are not traditional images. they have header contain information. This header is common between all the images. This data is located on an old server which has low capabilities.

I want  to make copy of the tree to another server which has better performance and copy one file (anyfile) within each sub folder to the new server.

I used

```
rsync -av -f"+ */" -f"- *" /path/to/src ssh user@xx.xx.xx.xx:/path/to/dest/
```

This command, really, created a new empty tree oon the new server. My question is:

How can I revise this command to enable it sync one file/ any file of every folder?

my question is more focused on the roles defined by the flags `f` how can I add new flag `f` for new role that tells `rsync` to sync one file from each folder and sub folder?

I can't use any solution that include `cp` `mv` or `find`. Running these commands on the old server and the huge amount of data will take forever!

Comment: What does "first" mean in this context?  The oldest?  The one whose name is alphanumerically smaller than the rest?

Comment: Why do you want to copy only one file from each folder? Maybe I'm missing something in your explanation.

Comment: @Zahi. Are the filenames in a particular folder have pattern of naming convention?

Comment: You do realise that although `find`/`cp` will traverse the filesystem, `rsync` will also traverse it? One is unlikely to be significantly slower than the other during traversal.

Answer (score -1):

Do this after your **rsync** command

```
find /path/to/src -type d | while read D; do F=$(find ${D} -maxdepth 1 -type f | head -1); test -z ${F} || cp ${F} "/path/to/dest$(echo ${F#path/to/src})"; done
```

This will copy the first file from each dir that contains any files

Comment: @Zahi, even with several thousand directories, each having just a thousand or so small files, it isn't a large amount of data. Really.